# Suppressing error in batch command if reg

Tags: command-line, windows-registry, batch-file

If I run the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\SomeApp\Server" /v ServerName') DO SET ServerName=%%B
ECHO Server:  %ServerName%
```

and the registry doesn't exist, it gives the following error

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

I know the error is expected, but how can suppress this error?

Not too concerned about the ECHO part showing just "SERVER:" with no value, that's fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message is coming because the `REG` command is writing to either the standard output stream or the standard error stream.  If you really don't care about the messages, you can [redirect that output](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110930) so that it is not displayed.

Change your command to:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\SomeApp\Server" /v ServerName > nul 2> nul
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. You need to escape redirect operator as mentioned in the other answer

Answer (score 7):

```dos
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('
    REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\SomeApp\Server" /v ServerName 2^> nul 
') DO SET "ServerName=%%B"

ECHO Server:  %ServerName%
```

Changes from your code:

- (not needed) `delims` removed. Tabs and spaces are the default delimiters, there is no need to include them
- (needed) The `stderr` stream (stream number 2) is redirected to nul device to hide the error output. The redirect operator `>` needs to be escaped when included inside the `for /f` command, from here the `^>`
- (recommended) `set` command is quoted to prevent problems with ending spaces or special characters in values. The quotes only protect the operation are not included in the value stored into the variable.